# set search domain on dhcp server without changing domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcpd

Suppose my company's domain is "company.com", our department's domain is "dept". How to set dhcp server in order to let our department's computers to search company.com? Or I have to set up a dns server?

I use Linux as dhcp server, "option domain-search " is not helpful in dhcpd.conf

Comment: What do you mean by "search"?

Answer (score 0):

In dhcp server we have only one parameter to configure a domain name: `option domain-name "dept.company.com";`.

So... you need to create a sub-domain in you dns server: `dept.company.com`.